# ASP.NET MVC: field is present but validation error says "Field is required"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5.2, validationerror

**Summary:**

When I want to update a Model instance inside database it cause validation error `Field is required` for `Client` field (Altough field is filled before saving and is not empty when I trace program).

**Details:**

I have a model `Project` as listed below:

```
namespace ProjectManager.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "نام پروژه")]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "{0} باید حداقل {2} و حداکثر {1} کاراکتری باشد")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "کارفرما")]
        [Required]
        public virtual ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Client")]
        public string ClientId{ get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "مدیر پروژه")]
        [Required]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ProjectManager { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProjectManager")]
        public string ProjectManagerId{ get; set; }

        [Range(0,100)]
        [Display(Name = "پیشرفت پروژه")]
        [Required]
        public int Progress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "تاریخ ثبت پروژه")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        [Column("Disabled")]
        [Display(Name = "غیرفعال")]
        public bool Disabled{ get; set; }

        //[Required]
        [Column("Status")]
        [Display(Name = "وضعیت")]
        public string Status{ get; set; }

        //-------------------- Payment Requests of Projects
        public virtual ICollection<PaymentRequest> PaymentRequests { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

    }
}
```

When I want to change Project progress, I use below controllers:

```
    public ActionResult UpdateProgress()
    {
        ApplicationUser projectManager = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        Project project = Utils.getProjectManagerProject(projectManager, db);
        EditProgressProjectViewModel model = new EditProgressProjectViewModel
        {
            Progress = project.Progress
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UpdateProgress(EditProgressProjectViewModel projectModel)
    {
        if (projectModel == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser projectManager = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            Project project = Utils.getProjectManagerProject(projectManager, db);
            project.Progress = projectModel.Progress;
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                Utils.addValidationErrorsToModelState(ModelState, e);
                return View(projectModel);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(projectModel);
    }
}
```

But trying to run db.saveChanges() cause validation errors which say "Field Client is required" but project.client is not empty and it is filled with value which fetched from database already.

Comment: No point adding a `[Required]` attribute to an `int` property unless you want a custom error message (an `int` cannot be `null`) and remove the `[Required]` attribute from `Client`. The model in your view is `EditProgressProjectViewModel` but all you have shown is `Project`

Comment: @StephenMuecke EditProgressProjectViewModel just contains an `int` field for progress. you mean I should change `int` to `int?` and use `[Required]` afterward? However how can I be sure i `Client` field is set with right value (it is not null or empty or something like this)?

Comment: If its `int` then the only reason to use a `RequiredAttribute` is to add a custom message (e.g. `[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a number")]`) because an `int` is always required (it cannot be `null`)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `[Required]` is defined in bad place,
it means instead of this declaration:

```
    [Display(Name = "کارفرما")]
    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public string ClientId{ get; set; }
```

this must be used:

```
    [Display(Name = "کارفرما")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    [Required] //**** Right Place for required annotation****
    public string ClientId{ get; set; }
```

`[Required]` should be placed for `ForeignKey` ID not `ForeignKey` Object.